# LDAP searchResEntry - order of values

Tags: active-directory, ldap

When I'm requesting a user information from MS AD through LDAP I'm getting "searchResEntry". One of user  attributes is "PartialAttributeList item memberOf" and it has "vals". It seems these "vals" are ordered from most recently created group to least recently created group. Is it possible to change default way the MS AD LDAP is responding and order these "vals" from least recently created group to most recently created group?
[image]
The software which I'm trying to integrate with AD is taking first group from the list of vals and I can't change it so I'm trying to influence the way MS LDAP responds.

Answer (score 0):

In a word no.
There is nothing in the LDAP that provides the order of values.

Some LDAP server distributions MAY return values in a specific order but nothing in the protocol is provided for this to take place.
I have observed some that appear to always return values on when they were added.

You should expect to order them on a the client.

Comment: I agree with you, LDAP has nothing to do with it. If I request the same data but using powershell `(Get-ADUser sst.proj1.usr -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object MemberOf).MemberOf` I'm getting the same groups in the same order - from the newest to the oldest. So this is the default order the AD DS is returning objects in. Can I influence this default order by changing some key in registry or any other way?

Comment: Not that I am aware.